How do i write a SOQL query in Power Automate where i need to get Id of Cases that dont contain specific keywords in their comment text
So, the SOQL query that I need should get the OrderNumbers that don't contain in the comment section any of these keywords: freigabe, Freigabe, DocCheck_approved but the output shows me all OrderNumbers that contain any of the 3 comment keywords I dont want to get.
I used
AND Id NOT IN (WHERE Comment LIKE '%Freigabe%'
OR Comment LIKE '%freigabe%'
OR Comment LIKE '%DocCheck_approved%'
)


step 1: run this query directly in SF (outside of Power Automate) and verify its output. step 2: let us know how you did.

This is for a different object but try something like this....
SELECT Id,Name 
FROM Contact  
WHERE NOT (Name LIKE '%Test%' OR Name LIKE '%Bobby%' Or Name like '%For%')

Change Contact to the object you want, Name to the field you want, and then the values in single quotes to what you want to exclude.
